# Awk script to Merge 2 columns in a text file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am writing a shell script and below is what I am trying to achieve.

I have a file - data.txt

data.txt contains,-

```
TMN     -23.50
JHS     5000.00
NHG     233768.90
```

I want to merge the data.txt to datanew.txt as follows,-

```
020TMN+000023.5000
020JHS+005000.0000
020NHG+233768.9000
```

Below .awk script works fine for doing this in a SunOS 5.8 server

```
 $ cat awkp.awk
 ( printf  "020%s%+06.4f         \n",$1,$2)
```

The awkp.awk is then called in my main script as

```
cat data.txt | awk -f awkp.awk > datanew.dat
```

But the same doesn't work in Linux 2.6.18

I have tried running my shell script in different shell environments as well like bash, korn and cshell but no luck.

Any ideas how I can get this output in Linux??

Comment: In the first line of your desired output,  `-23.50` was converted to `+000023.5000`.  Is the change in sign intentional?

Answer (score 1):

This works on linux:

```
$ awk '{printf  "020%s%+012.4f         \n",$1,$2}' data.txt
020TMN-000023.5000         
020JHS+005000.0000         
020NHG+233768.9000
```

Or, if you prefer the awk program in a separate file:

```
$ cat awkp3.awk
{printf  "020%s%+012.4f         \n",$1,$2}
$ awk -f awkp3.awk data.txt
020TMN-000023.5000         
020JHS+005000.0000         
020NHG+233768.9000
```

There were two changes required:

1. awk statements must be in curly braces, not parens.
2. The format width had to be increased from `%+06.4f` to `%+012.4f`.

The default awk on Sun OS is considered buggy.  When on Sun OS, consider using  `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`  or `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` instead.

Lastly, note that `cat` is not needed.  We can remove it and thereby reduce the number of processes that must be created.